# Perl regular expression returns only one value in list context even if multiple matching is possible

Tags: regex, perl

I am working with a Perl regular expression of this kind:

```
/(^.*)XXX/g
```

I want this regexp to match text of the type

```
******XXX****XXX***XXX
```

so that in this case the regexp would match three times and provide these results:

```
******XXX****XXX***
******XXX****
******
```

However, when I put this regexp in a list context like this

```
while($_=~/(^.*)XXX/g)
```

there's only one match and it is

```
******XXX****XXX***
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change your loop:

```
$_ = "******XXX****XXX***XXX";
while(/(.*)XXX/) {
    print $1,"\n";
    $_=$1;
}
```

The matched result is found in `$1` while the variable you're matching to is `$_`.

Comment: i think this workaround might work. however, this still doesn't explain why i'm not seeing all three matches in the first go.

Comment: @PatrickB - +1 because this solution even creates the desired order.

Comment: I understand now why my original thing doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: @TitoCandelli What you seem to look for it is an incremental-recursive matching or an "find all possible matches" with regex in perl on a variable - is that right?

Comment: @PatrickB. if i understand what incremental-recursive means correctly then yes. this solution works nicely, although i think there are probably more rigorous ones.

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use `` $` `` (`$PREMATCH`), this will get your desired result:

```
my $inp = "******XXX****XXX***XXX";
while ($inp =~ /XXX/g) {
  print $`, "\n";
}
```

output:

```
******
******XXX****
******XXX****XXX***
```

Your regex fails, because `^.*` matches 'everything' greedily.

Answer (score 1):

This is how one finds all possible matches:

```
local our @matches;
/^(.*)XXX(?{ push @matches, $1 })(?!)/sg;
say for @matches;  # Or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$str = '******XXX****XXX***XXX';

sub backwards {
    if( $_[0] =~ /(.*)XXX.*?$/) {
        print $1, "\n";
        backwards($1);
    }
}

backwards($str);
```

output:

```
******XXX****XXX***
******XXX****
******
```

Comment: @TitoCandelli : It's best to avoid recursion if at all possible. In this case there's no need to recurse

Comment: so what would you propose zaid?

Comment: @Tito Candelli: I *think* you need "@" for a notification (without the space): @ Zaid

Comment: @Zaid: [A slight delay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6gN1uO8w6Y&list=PLSoD2CcPrumFJREVL6RmMnZP5U7sGYYi2&index=12&t=7m40s)